# Don't wait for the answer just continue on batch

Tags: batch-file, continue, msgbox

```
wscript C:\open.vbs

ATTRIB -R -S -H "C:\add.txt" 
CD.>C:\add.txt 
goto end
```

Hey guys I have a code like this. It prompts a window from open.vbs and It wait for the answer to continue. It is waiting for my answer. But I want it to prompt and just continue if I don't even answer. How can I do that?

Comment: What is the purpose of `open.vbs`? It seems to me that you may just delete this line...

Comment: Prompting message from add.txt after that it makes add.txt empty. So if I don't answer it, it prompts unneccessary same windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
start "" wscript "c:\open.vbs"
```

Comment: That worked! Added wait command after these command, works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Start a separate [`cmd.exe`](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) process:

```
cmd.exe /c wscript C:\open.vbs
```

Or simply move your first line to the end in the case you don’t use results of `open.vbs`.

Comment: This won't work.  The VBS will run to conclusion and then a batch command following it will run.